# Interface and class merging when extending an abstract class

Tags: typescript

first of all thanks for your time.

My problem is :

```
abstract class Father {
    abstract property: string;
}

interface Son extends Father {

}

class Son {

}
```

In this case, there is [no warning](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgYsCALAplAgN4BQCFCokM8CADlAPb2EQCeAXAjQJYB2AcwDcpAL6lSAiIQBmcfAgDKTfgnwAPGfwAmGbHkIlJE0ijQYVasuKA) but i think it should because `Son` doesn't implement properly `Father` as it should define the `property` in the class `Son`

## First question

Is this really a bug?

## Second question

If this is a bug, what if `property` is not required (eg: `?:`)?

I think it should because `property` is abstract

## Third question

The Github issue tracker ask if this is a breaking change, so is it ?

## why this question is important to me

let's take this code:

```
abstract class Father {
    abstract property?: string;
}

abstract class Mother {
    constructor() {
        // do something
    }

    abstract method: () => void;
}

interface Son extends Father {

}

class Son extends Mother{
    method: () => void;

}
```

in my case, i need that `super` refer to `Mother` in the `Son` class but i need to respect the contract of `Father` as `property` is not required but `abstract`, So i think a warning should be trigger for not respecting `Father`.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a compiler bug here.  You seem to be [using a class as an interface](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#using-a-class-as-an-interface) along with [interface merging](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces), uncommon techniques that don't match your intent:

---

When you declare a class like

```
class Foo {
  x: number = 1;
}
```

you are both creating a named *value* called `Foo` which is a constructor object, *as well as* creating a named *type* called `Foo`, which is the type of an instance of the `Foo` class.  This named type is essentially the same as an `interface`, and can be used like an interface.  Often this distinction isn't very important, but when you do something like the following, it is:

```
interface Bar extends Foo {
  y: string
}
```

An interface can only extend another interface-like *type*; so here, `Bar` doesn't care about the fact that `Foo` is a class; all it's doing is viewing `Foo` as an interface like `{x: number}`, so `Bar` is equivalent to `{x: number; y: string}`.  In particular, if any of `Foo`'s properties are `abstract`, it will be completely invisible to `Bar`.  The `abstract`-ness only matters to subclass implementations.  `Bar` is not a subclass of `Foo`; it's an interface.  As far as `Bar` is concerned, it is an interface with an `x` and a `y` property.

---

When you have a `class` and an `interface` with the same name, what you are doing is *merging* the type declarations together:

```
class Bar {
    z: boolean = true;
}
```

By naming this class `Bar`, I've caused the type named `Bar` to gain a `z` property.  So now the `Bar` interface is equivalent to `{x: number, y: string, z: boolean}`.  The class implementation of `Bar` does not worry about the `x` and `y` properties because those are not declared inside the `Bar` class.  It assumes that the `x` and `y` properties have been taken care of by whoever merged them into the `Bar` interface. Indeed, this is one of the big use cases for declaration merging: the ability for someone to add new properties or methods to an existing class without having to alter the original class implementation code.  For example, you could add methods to an existing class by merging into the interface and assigning properties to the constructor's `prototype` (see [module augmentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation)).

In other words, the above pair of `Bar` declarations could be collapsed into a single `Bar` class like this:

```
class BarAlso {
    declare x: number; // declared but not implemented
    declare y: string; // declared but not implemented
    z: boolean = true; // implemented
}
```

where the `x` and `y` properties are simply [`declare`d](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier) without being implemented.

---

You are using features of TypeScript and they are behaving as intended.  So how can you get the behavior you actually want?  I'd recommend completely avoiding declaration merging; only have one type declaration for each class:

```
abstract class Father {
    abstract property: string;
}

class Son extends Father { // error!
    //~~~
    // does not implement inherited abstract member 'property' from class 'Father'
}
```

And since the *`class`* `Son` is declared to extend `Father`, you get your warning about not implementing the abstract property.

As for your example with `Mother`, it looks like you're trying to get something like [multiple inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance), which is not supported in JavaScript for `class`es.  I presume that's why you are using classes like they are interfaces, since you *can* implement multiple interfaces.

Since you've said you want `Son` to inherit from the `Mother` class, we can have `Son` extend `Mother` like a class, and then treat `Father` like an interface:

```
abstract class Father {
    abstract property: string;
}

abstract class Mother {
    constructor() {
        // do something
    }
    abstract method: () => void;
}

class Son extends Mother implements Father { // error!
    //~~~
    // 'property' is missing in type 'Son' but required in type 'Father'

    method = () => { }; 
}
```

The relevant piece is `class Son extends Mother implements Father`.  You're saying that `Son` will get the `Mother` class prototype in its prototype chain, but that it should be verified to be assignable to `Father` as an interface.  And you get an error that `Son` is not assignable to `Father` because it's missing the `property`.

---

So that's my suggestion: continue using classes as interfaces if you need to get something *like* multiple inheritance, and don't use declaration merging at all.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEARCYD2SDeBYAUEkUvADYhRRIBiGWehxTAHgFxLACuYARhAE5IAvEgCMAbgJMAvgSnEAlsAAuAgGYJkAIRCCIzVcAAmVWvXlMiAT3ZRl-JQHNJjIrPwWS5Skh2CGlsQAXuw8dKQQIMDCSPacEC4ycq5eFFR+AIKkUOYpTEYQZLrIbBzcfPziSAD01UgFRfwQRkg8nMocGB0KYDARkCrNnvmF5E1INkh2DsDONXUNY82t7Z3dvf0Qg0bDwaHhkdEicQnzSD196FuqOynu7gSgkLCaSADywMgMniA80wgdIo+aggZQACwEOF2RF+-3gHRg-AwMAEykm0yciWIDxSQKoAGUMNF9IYTDRQRD-GcBEj+ABCaHzAB+LMZtXqGGga3OGyuKnOwEpChuSFh9gBSEgvEhAHJEcjUVYZUg1EiwKkfDKQeCBDLPDicU9oHBEEgACoAd1ySGSTDF-AlePJOv8jPtEvlKP4aNs9kx+ttxHd8I1VAAsl1KVC8sR4ETppx4Rh+AAKACU0cCgXZRiwOUg4KcjJxWdFf3FIYLYIwRnY6eEAD4kAA3DAKIxYtyBohOwnEgxbMkRl08y4DZSmCmQ7DU-i0hkxoi1FlMtl1OVIr1o5UKKhgXdQJwC2JWFFIGV95VtDpNACOnAUTRaShPZ61U-4eo8i8lEHBNZieshCbGdpCqANv2kIA)

Comment: Thanks for that, i didn't search about implementing an `abstract` class because i assumed (badly) that if an `abstract` property isn't required (eg `?:`) in `Father`, i wouldn't need to redefine it in the `Son` class. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from a c++ viewpoint you really should not be using 2 classes with the same name that mean two different things, is Son a concrete class or an interface?

Your example is kind of strange, inheritance works as a "is a" relationship whereas this example should work as a "has a".

E.g.

```
Class Person
{
}

Class Father : public Person // this is an inheritance relationship - "is-a"
{
}

Class Mother : public Person
{
}

Class Son : public Person
{
Private:
Father m_Father; // this is a composition relationship - "has a"
Mother m_Mother;
}
```